Implementation guidance for Mobile Robot Path Planning in Dynamic Environments Through Globally Guided Reinforcement Learning
I have been working with the implementation of a mobile robot control paper, which guides an agent in a dynamic environment with unknown trajectories. I mostly worked by the paper's explanations: paper, but my model doesn't seem to converge. I trained both a DQN and a PPO agent for around 100 thousand episodes, and debugged potential issues for quite a while now but nothing yielded "good-like" results. I'm a second year BSc student and would say I'm only exploring reinforcement learning concepts, so any advice would be well appreciated. I'm generally asking about implementation structure and initializations, do I make a rookie mistake in the base code or did I misunderstand something? I'm generally interested in my maskPPO agent's and my CNN model's correctness, are they implemented correctly..? My git repo is reachable here with the full project: repo
If anyone takes the time to have look, it would be much appreciated.
maskPPO agent:
class MaskPPOAgent:
    def __init__(self, env, model, device='cpu', batch_size=32, mini_batch_size=8, epochs=4, gamma=0.99, gae_lambda=0.95, clip_epsilon=0.2, c1=0.5, c2=0.01, lr=3e-4):
        self.env = env
        self.model = model
        self.device = device
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.mini_batch_size = mini_batch_size
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.gae_lambda = gae_lambda
        self.clip_epsilon = clip_epsilon
        self.c1 = c1  # Value function coefficient
        self.c2 = c2  # Entropy coefficient
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=lr, eps=1e-5)
        self.replay_buffer = PrioritizedReplayBuffer(capacity=10000)
        
        # Logging
        self.policy_losses = []
        self.value_losses = []
        self.entropies = []
        self.kl_divs = []

        self.debug = 1

    def select_action(self, state):
        if self.debug:
            print("Debug: Selecting action")
            print(f"Debug: Input state shape: {state.shape}")
        
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().to(self.device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            action_logits, state_value = self.model(state, return_value=True)
            action_probs = torch.softmax(action_logits, dim=-1)

            mask = self.env.get_action_mask(self.device)
            if self.debug:
                print(f"Debug: Action probabilities before masking: {action_probs}")
                print(f"Debug: Action mask: {mask}")
            
            action_probs = action_probs * mask
            
            if self.debug:
                print(f"Debug: Action probabilities after masking: {action_probs}")

            if action_probs.sum() > 0:
                action_probs = action_probs / action_probs.sum(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
                if self.debug:
                    print(f"Debug: Action probabilities after probability sum: {action_probs}")
                action_distribution = torch.distributions.Categorical(action_probs)
                if self.debug:
                    print(f"Debug: Action distribution: {action_distribution}")
                action = action_distribution.sample()
                log_prob = action_distribution.log_prob(action)
            else:
                action = torch.tensor(4, device=self.device)
                log_prob = torch.tensor(0.0, device=self.device)

            if self.debug:
                print(f"Debug: Action selected: {action.item()}")
                print(f"Debug: Log probability: {log_prob.item()}")
                print(f"Debug: State value: {state_value.item()}")

        return action.item(), log_prob.item(), state_value.item()

    def store(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done, log_prob, value):
        experience = (state, action, reward, next_state, done, log_prob, value)
        self.replay_buffer.add(experience)

    def update(self, states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones, log_probs, values):
        if self.debug:
            print("Debug: Starting update")

        advantages, returns = self.compute_advantages_and_returns(rewards, values, dones)
        if self.debug:
            print(f"Debug: Advantages: {advantages}, returns: {returns}")

        states = torch.from_numpy(np.array(states)).float().to(self.device)
        actions = torch.from_numpy(np.array(actions)).long().to(self.device)
        old_log_probs = torch.from_numpy(np.array(log_probs)).float().to(self.device)
        advantages = torch.from_numpy(advantages).float().to(self.device)
        returns = torch.from_numpy(returns).float().to(self.device)
        old_values = torch.from_numpy(np.array(values)).float().to(self.device)

        states = states.squeeze(1)
        advantages = (advantages - advantages.mean()) / (advantages.std() + 1e-8)

        if self.debug:
            print(f"Debug: Normalized advantages mean: {advantages.mean()}, std: {advantages.std()}")

        action_logits, state_values = self.model(states, return_value=True)
        new_log_probs = torch.distributions.Categorical(torch.softmax(action_logits, dim=-1)).log_prob(actions)
        entropy = torch.distributions.Categorical(torch.softmax(action_logits, dim=-1)).entropy().mean()

        ratio = torch.exp(new_log_probs - old_log_probs)
        surrogate1 = ratio * advantages
        surrogate2 = torch.clamp(ratio, 1 - self.clip_epsilon, 1 + self.clip_epsilon) * advantages
        policy_loss = -torch.min(surrogate1, surrogate2).mean()

        values_clipped = old_values + (state_values - old_values).clamp(-self.clip_epsilon, self.clip_epsilon)
        value_loss1 = (state_values - returns).pow(2)
        value_loss2 = (values_clipped - returns).pow(2)
        value_loss = 0.5 * torch.max(value_loss1, value_loss2).mean()

        loss = policy_loss + self.c1 * value_loss - self.c2 * entropy

        if self.debug:
            print(f"Debug: Policy loss: {policy_loss.item()}")
            print(f"Debug: Value loss: {value_loss.item()}")
            print(f"Debug: Entropy: {entropy.item()}")
            print(f"Debug: Total loss: {loss.item()}")

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.model.parameters(), max_norm=0.5)
        self.optimizer.step()

        # Logging
        self.policy_losses.append(policy_loss.item())
        self.value_losses.append(value_loss.item())
        self.entropies.append(entropy.item())
        approx_kl_div = ((old_log_probs - new_log_probs) ** 2).mean().item()
        self.kl_divs.append(approx_kl_div)

        if self.debug:
            print(f"Debug: Approximate KL divergence: {approx_kl_div}")
            print("Debug: Update completed")

    def compute_advantages_and_returns(self, rewards, values, dones):
        advantages = np.zeros_like(rewards)
        returns = np.zeros_like(rewards)
        last_gae_lam = 0
        
        for t in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
            if t == len(rewards) - 1:
                next_non_terminal = 1.0 - dones[t]
                next_value = 0
            else:
                next_non_terminal = 1.0 - dones[t + 1]
                next_value = values[t + 1]
            
            delta = rewards[t] + self.gamma * next_value * next_non_terminal - values[t]
            advantages[t] = last_gae_lam = delta + self.gamma * self.gae_lambda * next_non_terminal * last_gae_lam

        # Handle the last timestep separately
        advantages[-1] = rewards[-1] - values[-1]

        returns = advantages + values
        return advantages, returns

    def replay_buffer_update(self):
        if len(self.replay_buffer) < self.batch_size:
            return

        states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones, log_probs, values, _, _ = self.replay_buffer.sample(self.batch_size)
        self.update(states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones, log_probs, values)

    def adjust_learning_rate(self, step, total_steps):
        lr = 3e-4 * (1 - step / total_steps)
        for param_group in self.optimizer.param_groups:
            param_group['lr'] = lr

    def get_logs(self):
        logs = {
            'policy_loss': np.mean(self.policy_losses),
            'value_loss': np.mean(self.value_losses),
            'entropy': np.mean(self.entropies),
            'approx_kl_div': np.mean(self.kl_divs)
        }
        self.policy_losses = []
        self.value_losses = []
        self.entropies = []
        self.kl_divs = []
        return logs

CNN model class:
class CNNLSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, height=15, width=15, nt=4, nc=3, dropout_rate=0.2):
        super(CNNLSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.nc = nc
        self.conv_blocks = nn.ModuleList()
        
        in_channels = nt
        out_channels = 32
        for _ in range(nc):
            self.conv_blocks.append(nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(0, 1, 1)),
                nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout3d(dropout_rate),
                nn.Conv3d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), stride=(1, 2, 2), padding=(0, 1, 1)),
                nn.BatchNorm3d(out_channels),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Dropout3d(dropout_rate)
            ))
            in_channels = out_channels
            out_channels *= 2
        
        self.lstm_input_size = 128 * 2 * 2 * 4
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=self.lstm_input_size, hidden_size=512, batch_first=True)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 5)
        
        self.value_head = nn.Linear(512, 1)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        
        self.apply(self.orthogonal_init)

    
    def forward(self, x, return_value=False):
        # print(f"Input shape before processing: {x.shape}")
        batch_size, nt, height, width, channels = x.shape

        x = x.permute(0, 4, 1, 2, 3).contiguous()  # Change to (batch_size, nt, channels, height, width)
        # print(f"Input shape after permute: {x.shape}")
        
        for conv_block in self.conv_blocks:
            x = conv_block(x)

        # print(f"Shape after conv block: {x.shape}")
        
        # Flatten the spatial dimensions and combine with the time dimension
        _, c, t, h, w = x.shape
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3, 4).contiguous()
        x = x.view(batch_size, t, -1)

        # print(f"Shape after flatten: {x.shape}")
        
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        lstm_out = lstm_out[:, -1, :]  # Take the last output

        # print(f"Shape after lstm block: {x.shape}")
        
        x = self.fc1(lstm_out)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)

        # print(f"Shape after first linear + relu: {x.shape}")
        
        action_logits = self.fc2(x)

        # print(f"Shape after second linear + relu: {x.shape}")
        
        if return_value:
            value = self.value_head(x).squeeze(-1)
            return action_logits, value
        
        return action_logits
    
    def orthogonal_init(self, module):
        if isinstance(module, (nn.Conv3d, nn.Linear)):
            nn.init.orthogonal_(module.weight, gain=np.sqrt(2))
            if module.bias is not None:
                nn.init.constant_(module.bias, 0)
        elif isinstance(module, nn.LSTM):
            for name, param in module.named_parameters():
                if 'weight' in name:
                    nn.init.orthogonal_(param, gain=np.sqrt(2))
                elif 'bias' in name:
                    nn.init.constant_(param, 0)
        elif isinstance(module, nn.BatchNorm3d):
            nn.init.constant_(module.weight, 1)
            nn.init.constant_(module.bias, 0)

        # Recursively initialize submodules
        for child in module.children():
            self.orthogonal_init(child)

CNN model receives an 5D input as:
(batch_size, time_dim, obs_width, obs_height, chanels: rgb + local part of the global guidance)
in a particular example (128,4,30,30,4), where a 128 sized batch is processed, with 1 present and 3 past observations, a size 15 local field of view and rgb + global guidance chanels.
Thanks if you read it this far, and huge thanks if you could provide professional advice!
Thanks,
Mark
I tried debugged the code and checked implementations, and in my opinion (might be really wrong) it should be converging to an optimal policy, but after several steps it fails to generalize:
--------------------------97950'th episode - 1959'th start-end pair ---------------------------
Reward: 0.03, Computing time: 1693.26 min/50 epochs
Goal reached for start-goal pair: 0 times, Number of collisions: 0
Terminations casued by - Reached goals: 3229.0, No guidance information: 19731.0, Max steps reached: 75107.0
100 epoch Policy Loss: 0.0076
100 epoch Value Loss: 1.7975
100 epoch Entropy: 1.2725
100 epoch KL Divergence: 0.0534

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
